SSH Command to call a remote (Raspberry Pi) Python script using Matlab
I've been trying to run and get the output of a remote Python file that is on a Raspberry Pi.
The original file captures signals, but I just created a simple python file to see if it can work.
The python file is:
L = 1 + 5
print(L)

The MATLAB file looks like this:
clc
close all
clear

% Define the SSH command to run the Python script on the Raspberry Pi
sshCommand = 'ssh id@ipaddress "python3.11 /home/mcc128/Desktop/RaspTest.py"';

% Execute the SSH command and capture the output
[status, cmdout] = system(sshCommand);

(I used the correct id and ip address. Omitted them for the sake of anonymity.)
When I run the file, MATLAB just gets stuck running the execution line forever. I don't get any error messages, just that it loads forever. Since it is a relatively simple task, it shouldn't take this long to run it. I think there's a mistake somewhere (in the code or that this function is just not supported etc.), but I can't figure it out.
Note: I can't install the MATLAB raspberry pi support because it isn't compatible with the raspberry pi OS.

How have you set up authentication? Have you set up keys to authenticate with the remote? Does ssh id@ipaddress echo foo work on your console without user-interaction? There's a chance that ssh is waiting for a password to be entered, but nothing ever enters it.

Thank you, that was the problem and it works now!
